# City Registration in Germany

Tags: germany, residency

Is city registration associated with the length of the rental contract?

I did my city registration last year when I moved to Germany, My rental contract will end next month which I am planning to extend, Do I need to go through the process of city registration again for the same address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Anmeldung` process in Germany is about registering your place of residence for the authorities, and until you inform them otherwise then they will assume that you remain at the same place and they don't care about details such as the length of your rental contract which is between you and your landlord and hence not relevant to them.
They only want the contract, or a letter from the landlord, to prove that you live there.

So you must only inform them when you move-in, move-out, or change your address.  A process that must be done within 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter HOW you manage your stay at the specific address , could be a friend of yours or a relieve , but you need to inform **Burgeramt** and get the **Anmeldung**  which shows you're place of residence is this address

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply renewing your lease, you do not need to make a new Anmeldung.